# Error when read hbase within spark rdd foreach action

Tags: apache-spark, foreach, hbase, spark-streaming

I am trying to use spark streaming to consume a kafka message queue, within the foreachRdd operation, I am trying to read hbase within a rdd foreach action according to the messages that taking out from kafka. But I am getting some errors, looks like there are some dead lock. Anybody can help me figure out what's the issue here?
Below is the code details.

```
    KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext,kafkazk,kafkaGroup,kafkaTopic.split(",").map(_.trim -> 1).toMap)
.foreachRDD(_.processRDD(new CQRequestContext(null,new DBRequestContext(prefix,dbName,tableName,null,null,null))))
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

I am trying to do some hbase read with in each rdd foreach action, I am trying to create a hbase connection inthe foreachPartition action, in order to reduce the connection numbers.

```
def processRDD(cQRequestContext: CQRequestContext) = {
     rdd.foreachPartition(iterator=>{
          val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(HbaseUtil.getHbaseConfiguration("FdsCQ"));
          val hTable= connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("cqdev:sampleTestTable"))

      try {
      iterator.foreach(requestTuple =>{
        //processAIPRequest(requestTuple._2,cQRequestContext,myTable)

          val p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("dabao12345"))
          p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.RESPONSE_CONTENT), Bytes.toBytes("content"))
          p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.PACKAGE_NOS), Bytes.toBytes("response"))
          p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.ABUSE_PACKAGES_NO), Bytes.toBytes("response"))
          p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.RESPONSE_CODE), Bytes.toBytes("responseCode"))
          p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(SellerConstants.CQ_ABUSE_RESULT.RESPONSE_STATUS), Bytes.toBytes("respone"))
          hTable.put(p)

      })

      } finally {
        //scanner.close
        hTable.close()
        connection.close()
      }


    })
```

}

And finally, I am getting below error, After debug I found this is not something like running out of connection from hbase, During testing I only put one message into kafka, and when the first time I am trying to create the hbase connection, I got the below errors.

```
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.submitRequest(ClientCnxn.java:1342)
org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1036)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:481)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:86)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:849)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:670)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
com.XXXXXXXX.func.CQStreamingFunction$$anonfun$processRDD$1.apply(CQStreamingFunction.scala:50)
com.XXXXXXXX.func.CQStreamingFunction$$anonfun$processRDD$1.apply(CQStreamingFunction.scala:49)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:898)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:898)
org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Further more the above error only happens, when I try to run my spark streaming job in yarn-cluster mode in a yarn cluster,  When I run in local mode in my local machine and connect to the remote hbase, everything works fine.

Env Details: CDH 5.5.2  with spark 1.5.0

Comment: seems like this is zookeeper issue. where its not able to establish client connection

Comment: you can monitor zookeeper health by CM. if needed restart the service and see

Comment: But, If I run a normal spark job on the cluster , I can operate the hbase DB, there is no issues getting the hbase connection. Which means there should be no issues for my clusters connect to my zookeeper servers.

Comment: have you checked https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#important_configurations?

Comment: can you list out all the configuration you applied? like hbase.rpc.timeout, lease period etc..

Comment: use HBaseConfiguration.create().writeXml(System.out); this will print all hbase configuration settings applied from different sources in unified way.. use this from caller where you are creating hbaseconfiguration.create()

Comment: Below is the rpc timeout<property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>

Comment: Below are all the detials of hbase-site.xml

Comment: <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://nameservice1/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.replication</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.write.buffer</name>
    <value>4194304</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.pause</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
    <value>35</value>
  </property>

Comment: <property>
    <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
    <value>500</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
    <value>10485760</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.ipc.client.allowsInterrupt</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.primaryCallTimeout.get</name>
    <value>10</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.primaryCallTimeout.multiget</name>
    <value>10</value>
  </property>

Comment: <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.thrift.http</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.master.timeoutMillis</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.region.timeout</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>

Comment: <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.master.timeout.millis</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
    <value>simple</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.protection</name>
    <value>authentication</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
  </property>

Comment: <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.rootserver</name>
    <value>root-region-server</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>xxxxx-prod07-mp,xxxxx-prod05-mp,xxxxx-prod06-mp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rest.ssl.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>

Comment: BTW, if I collect the rdd to driver then foreach, everything works fine. The issue only happens when try to get connection with in rdd operation.

Comment: that means driver is able to recognize your connection right ? can you create a broadcast variable of your hbase configuration and send it to for each partition that should work

Comment: Thanks Ram, Finally, I fixed the issue, looks like there are some issues with the code for generate the Configuration , the zookeeper related params can not beed loaded from config file when the code running in executors, that's why the connection can not been created.